# Hibernate + beanLib copy entity problems

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to fetch an Entity from the DB using hibernate, copy it removing all it's links to hibernate and then, if needed, persist the copy. In the end, both the original and the copy are in the DB.

My entity has a lot of children entities, grandchildren, and so on. Some of them may even be in Collections.

The copy must be a deep recursive copy, i.e. the children must also be copied and put in the new object.

I'm using beanLib and it is copying the entity correctly. Persistend bads are turned into Array lists, and I've checked the children to see if they're different objects from the originals. Here's my code:

```
Session sess = getDbSession();      
Dossier doss = (Dossier) sess.createCriteria(Dossier.class)
                             .add(Restrictions.eq("id", 1249))
                             .uniqueResult();

Hibernate3BeanReplicator rep = new Hibernate3BeanReplicator();
rep.initPropertyFilter(new MyBeanLibPropertyFilter()); // filters ids. works correctly

Dossier doss2 = rep.copy(doss, Dossier.class);
```

I have two problems:

1- <strike>One of the copy's children has values set to null. They're `nullable=false` in the hibernate annotations, and I've checked and they have values in the original. The field's type is `Double` (don't know if it's relevant).</strike> Solved! Getters and setters weren't named according to the naming conventions.

2- <strike>Using `session.persist(doss2)` doesn't persist the object. I even tried to close the session and then open it again, with no success.</strike> Solved! Missing `tx.commit();`

**SO if preventing me from answering my own question. When I can, I will post an answer.**

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT :** The commit code:

```
Transaction tx = null;
try {
    tx = sess.beginTransaction();
    sess.save(doss2);
    tx.commit();
    sess.flush();
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (tx != null) {
        tx.rollback();
    }
    throw e;
}
```

Comment: first that i'll do, put a break point and test if sess(session) is null.

Comment: sess is not null. Wouldn't sess.persist() throw an exception if it were?

Comment: well, it depends the kind of exception, but if session is working, maybe the problem was in the mapping, we are closer.

Comment: Remember that toy need to open.transaction and commit to persist object.

Comment: Ok, but the changes should be small. Changing the entities mapping should be one of the last options. We have a large number of entities, being used by several different systems. The entity copying is just a small need in the project. - Gonna add to the post the commiting instruction.

Comment: maybe someone here with more knowledge and experience can help you. when i find sth like your problem, i debug step to step to focus the error point. i'm sorry.

Comment: It's ok. Thanks for your help. The main error, right now, is that the call to `sess.persist(doss2)` doesn't actually persist the object. I don't know how to better debug it that running the code and checking the DB.

Comment: well..i suppose you know but I use to put a break point and take a look to the object and compare with the mapping.

Comment: The original and the copy are different objects but have the same data (except for ids and the problem in (2)). I confirmed it.

Comment: and what is the message of the exception? can you tell me?

Comment: No Exception. The object just isn't persisted.

Comment: Yeah! Thats it. I feel like a newbie. Thanks. Maybe write an answer. There's still the issue with the missing Doubles.

Comment: yeahhhhhhhhhhhh!!!!!!! don't worry about the points!!